# Deploying Nodejs Docker container with Nginx

Tags: javascript, node.js, docker, nginx, docker-compose

I recently finished building an application and would like to deploy it on a PaaS platform such as render. I read that using nginx as reverse proxy is good for production and I followed a tutorial to setup Nginx with docker container. It's my first time of trying out this process. I tested the nginx setup on postman and it worked fine.
I can make requests to my api via the nginx port. Now, I want to deploy the file to render using docker-compose.
To test this system in my nextjs application, I had to change the server endpoint from:
`export const BASE_URL = "http://localhost:4000/api/v1"` my server endpoint
to
`export const BASE_URL = "http://localhost:80/api/v1";`

If I deploy this setup on render, how do I make use of it or ensure that my requests hit the nginx endpoint. Render provides a free domain with option to link your own custom domain.
At this stage, I am lost and confused on next step to take.

Here are my setups:

//docker compose file

`version: "3" services: bookingapi: build: . image: kings19/bookingapi ports: \- "4000:4000" env_file: \- /src/Services/EnvConfig/.env nginx: depends_on: \- bookingapi restart: always build: dockerfile: Dockerfile context: ./nginx ports: \- "80:80"`

//Nginx docker file
  `FROM nginx   COPY ./nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf`

//Nginx confi file
`

```
events {}

http {
  upstream bookingapi {
    server bookingapi:4000;

}

server {
listen [::]:80;
  listen 80;

location /api {
    proxy_pass http://bookingapi;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Connection "";
}

}
}
```

`

Attach is my project structure:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hVuiZ.png)

Comment: "I want to deploy the file to render using docker-compose".  As far as I'm aware Render doesn't support that.  You're going to need to provide documentation if that is wrong.

Comment: oh, interesting, thanks. I actually read from render forum where they said most of their customers don't need this. The reason I wanted to do this is because I read that I can use nginx to handle the https which helps to make my application more secured. I must confess that I have limited experience on this. Will render also handle the https part for me then?

Comment: "Will render also handle the https part for me then?"  That's my understanding. It should detect the port you're using and do the proxy itself with provided certificates assuming you're following something like this https://docs.render.com/custom-domains

Comment: Thank you so much, I think this clears my doubt. Thanks for not ignoring my question because I was confused.

Comment: Your `docker-compose.yml` and `Dockerfile` are hard to read. Try editing your question using triple-backquote [fenced code blocks](https://www.markdownguide.org/extended-syntax/#fenced-code-blocks)

Answer (score 0):

What about referring to some samples like this?

https://github.com/Andrew-Kang-G/docker-blue-green-runner

- Use Docker & Docker-Compose
- With your project and its only Dockerfile, Docker-Blue-Green-Runner handles the rest of the Continuous Deployment (CD) process with Consul. Nginx allows your project to be deployed without experiencing any downtime.
- Consul & Registrator supported but they doesn't affect the availability of Nginx.
- Consider careful exceptional cases
- Available on one server machine